# keypress event in Android only fires for the return button

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I have this simple code that needs to fire after the user enters text into a textarea with id "input1".
It works perfectly except that Android (4.1 I believe) only registers the Enter button as a keypress. Other text entries are ignored. My code:

HTML

```
<textarea rows='4' cols='50' id='input1' maxlength='140' />
```

jQuery

```
$("#input1").keypress(function(key) {
     console.log("text was entered...");
});
```

Comment: Is this a mobile web site RUNNING on Android, or a WebView within an Android Activity?  Is this an emulator, or a real device?

Comment: Ah, sorry, it's a website that I'm viewing in Chrome on an Android tablet.

Comment: did you try using keydown and keyup?